# How to plot even and odd parts of log-Gabor filter?

Tags: filters, gabor

I am reading a [paper](http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:241550/FULLTEXT01.pdf) inwhich there is a plot of log-Gabor quadrature pair which are even and odd.

[image]

I'm wondering how these two are plotted in time-domain, since log-gabor is real valued in frequency-domain and I cannot use inverse Fourier of real/imaginary part to result in even/odd parts in time-domain!

Does anyone have an idea?